# MYSQL two tables query vs one of a time

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    cms_mod_lajmet_entry.LajmID, 
    page_id, date, 
    foto, eshte_video, 
    title, intro, 
    komente 
FROM cms_mod_lajmet_entry, cms_mod_lajmet_entry_language 
WHERE cms_mod_lajmet_entry.LajmID = cms_mod_lajmet_entry_language.LajmID 
    AND cms_mod_lajmet_entry.page_id = 2  
    AND cms_mod_lajmet_entry.publikimi = 1 
    AND cms_mod_lajmet_entry_language.language = 'sq' 
    AND cms_mod_lajmet_entry.renditja > 0 
ORDER by renditja ASC, date DESC LIMIT 1
```

(loading time = 0.1219)

when I split them:

```
SELECT 
    LajmID, 
    page_id, 
    date, 
    foto, 
    eshte_video, 
    komente 
FROM cms_mod_lajmet_entry 
WHERE cms_mod_lajmet_entry.page_id = 2  
    AND cms_mod_lajmet_entry.publikimi = 1 
    AND cms_mod_lajmet_entry.renditja > 0 ORDER by renditja ASC, date DESC LIMIT 1
```

(loading time = 0.0801)

and query this alone: ($t[LajmID] is a PrimaryID from the last table)

```
SELECT 
    title, 
    intro 
FROM cms_mod_lajmet_entry_language 
WHERE LajmID = $t[LajmID] 
    AND language = 'sq'
```

(Loadin time = 0.0006)

in total: 0.1219 > 0.0807 (0.0801 + 0.0006).

Is this really faster as it looks and/or if there's any other faster ways.

Indexes are as follows:

First table:

LajmID    BTREE No  No
LajmID    36380 A
page_id   36380 A
publikimi 36380 A
klika     36380 A

Second table:

LajmID   BTREE  No  No
LajmID   38456  A
language 38456  A

Comment: can you format your code? it will be much easier to read

Comment: To get accurate execution times, make sure you add `SQL_NO_CACHE` to the query so the query cache doesn't skew the results.  I can almost guarantee that that's why the second individual query is so fast.

Comment: Can you post an `EXPLAIN` of all of the queries?  It looks like the indexes you mentioned are composite, in which case it looks like they won't always be utilized.

Comment: Here's the Explain of the first query: 
`code`
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE cms_mod_lajmet_entry ALL PRIMARY,LajmID NULL NULL NULL 36846 Using where; Using filesort
1 SIMPLE cms_mod_lajmet_entry_language eq_ref PRIMARY,LajmID PRIMARY 11 cms.cms_mod_lajmet_entry.LajmID,const 1 Using where
`code`

Comment: First query time with SQL_NO_CACHE: 0.0727 sec
Second query time: 0.0712 sec
Third query time: 0.0008 sec)

Comment: You need an index on the first table that this query can use.  The index you mention in the question can't be used because it starts with `LajmID`, which is not used in the first table in this query.  If you create a single or composite index containing one or all of the fields used in the mentioned query, the performance will increase significantly.

Comment: Thanks, G-Nugget, already figured out exactly as you said it, and started using this one: page_id, publikimi, renditja and skipped second ordering by date DESC and left if out of the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't originally planning on answering, but my comments on the question basically answered it.  My comments are summarized below:

To get accurate query execution times, make sure you run the queries with `SQL_NO_CACHE`.  This will make sure that the query cache doesn't skew the results.  The index on the first table wasn't being used since `LajmID` was on the top of it and it wasn't used in the query.